# UK Citizen wanting to immigrate to USA and work

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, working-visas, immigration

I am currently a permanent citizen of the United Kingdom and I desire to immigrate to the USA.

I understand that I can only really do such things by getting a work VISA and essentially finding an employer who will sponsor me to immigrate.

How do I go about finding such employers? are there any services or agencies which will consulate with me and look for jobs on my behalf?

Comment: If you have not already done so, read https://www.uscis.gov/eir/visa-guide/h-1b-specialty-occupation/understanding-h-1b-requirements.